# How to join a derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complex query which results in a table which includes a `time` column. There are always two rows with the same `time`:

[image]

The result also contains a `value` column. The `value` of two rows with the same `time` is always different.

I now want to extend the query to join the rows with the same `time` together. So my thought was to join the derived table like this:

```
SELECT A.time, A.value AS valueA, B.value as valueB FROM
(
    OLD_QUERY
) AS A INNER JOIN A AS B ON 
A.time=B.time AND
A.value <> B.value;
```

However, the `JOIN A AS B` part of the query does not work. `A` is not recognized as the derived table. MySQL is searching for a table `A` in the database and does not find it.

So the question is: How can I join a derived table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot join a single reference to a table (or subquery) to itself; a subquery must be repeated.

Example: You cannot even do 
`SELECT A.* FROM sometable AS A INNER JOIN A ...`
The `A` after the INNER JOIN is invalid unless you actually have a real table called A.

You can insert the subquery's results into another table, and use that; but it cannot be a true TEMPORARY table, as those cannot be joined to themselves or referenced twice at all in almost any query. _By referenced twice, I mean joined, unioned, used as an "WHERE IN" subquery when it is already referenced in the FROM.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else distinguishes the rows, you can just use aggregation to get the two values:

```
select time, min(value), max(value)
from (<your query here>) a
group by time;
```

In MySQL 8+, you can use a cte:

```
with a as (
      <your query here>
     )
select a1.time, a1.value, a2.value
from a a1 join
     a a2
     on a1.time = a2.time and a1.value <> a2.value;
```